# "Asset File Not Found" (16/3002); "Can't read the file"

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I want so save an `CKAsset` and I get back this error: *Asset File Not Found" (16/3002); "Can't read the file*

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error means that the file didn't exist when CloudKit tried to upload the file backing the `CKAsset` to the server. This could be for one of two reasons:

1. The `fileURL` for the asset points at a file that doesn't exist.
2. The file was removed before the `CKModifyRecordsOperation` completed.

When saving an asset you need to keep the backing file around until the `CKModifyRecordsOperation` completes successfully.

Double-check that the file at the URL you're passing to `-[CKAsset initWithFileURL:]` can be opened by your process.